# Keyboard layout isn't kept upon reboot

Tags: keyboard-layout

I had a problem with the keyboard layout changing from PT (I'm Portuguese) to EN automatically with the last Ubuntu updates in Ubuntu 13.10. After Ubuntu 14.04 came out, I formatted my computer and installed the new version.

After that I haven't had any problems until the recent Ubuntu base update 2 or 3 days ago, when I started having the same problem again. I even removed the English keyboard from the Keyboard configurations, left only the Portuguese one, but still, every time I reboot my PC I get the keyboard configured for EN, despite Ubuntu displaying the contrary?

How can I remove this? I don't want to format the PC again and I'm getting really tired of this problem, since it looks like many Portuguese/Brasilian Ubuntu users are having the same problem.

Comment: This could be a similar issue to this problem
http://askubuntu.com/questions/367209/keyboard-layout-changing-from-uk-to-us-not-showing-as-changed-in-settings The solution worked for me (resetting it back to UK layout) might work here.

Comment: There is a relevant bug report here (I think) https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729423 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272

Comment: It is not off-topic since the version in question is not a development version and was supposed to be not only *stable*, but *Long-Term Support*. Trying to tag it as off-topic seems like a political move.

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362973/keyboard-layout-switches-to-english-each-time-i-reboot

Comment: As this is a question for a workaround and no bug report I don't really understand why it has been closed as off-topic.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/454646/keyboard-layout-en-after-boot and http://askubuntu.com/questions/367209/keyboard-layout-changing-from-uk-to-us-not-showing-as-changed-in-settings and http://askubuntu.com/questions/362973/keyboard-layout-switches-to-english-each-time-i-reboot . Bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198

Answer (score 9):

Found a solution for me.

[image: Keyboard configuration]

On terminal:

```
$ # If dconf-editor is not already installed
$ sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
$ dconf-editor
```

When the program opens do the following:

- navigate to **desktop.ibus.general**
  [image]
- remove `'xkb:us::eng'` from both **engines-order** and **preload-engines**
  [image]

Works for me on Brazilian Portuguese, hope that works for you.

Comment: It worked for some time, but after a while it added the english layout automatically on both engines-order and preload-engines.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to be a known Bug in 14.04.

What you can try is reconfiguring the keyboard data via the Terminal.

**sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data**

Click on the Keyboard Icon on the top and select your keyboard.

I know this is a hit or miss solution and I’ll keep searching for that article that references these steps to see if others have had success.

**Edit**

I Located the article i was thinking of - [keyboard layout EN after boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454646/keyboard-layout-en-after-boot)

Comment: unfortunately the problem persists... I can't understand why they would release a "stable version" with these bugs, when they had been informed about them in the 13.10 and 13.04 versions.

Comment: This works for me (ubuntu 14.04 french kbd)

Comment: Still happening on 17.04!